# OutOfMemoryException when upload file to Google Drive using Google Drive API

Tags: c#, http, google-drive-api, arrays

This is a web application.I am tying to upload large files to Google Drive using GoogleDrive API. My code works fine with smaller files. But when it comes to larger files error occurs.

I had search a lot, but couldn't find a solution for work and some of the tread that do not has a answer.

Error occurs in the code part where the the file is converted into byte[].

```
byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dir);
```

For **web.config** I had trying to change the request length, but it not work for a large files.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="520000" maxRequestLength="920000"  />
```

Anyone has a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Below is the full code.

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using ASPSnippets.GoogleAPI;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GoogleDriveAutoUpdate
{
    public partial class GoogleDriveSample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static int flagUpdateFile;
        protected string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\RNKP74\Desktop\GoogleDrive");


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GoogleConnect.ClientId = "";
            GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "";
            GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
            GoogleConnect.API = EnumAPI.Drive;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
                GoogleConnect.Authorize("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file");

            if (flagUpdateFile == 0)
                UploadFile();
        }

        protected HttpPostedFile ConstructHttpPostedFile(byte[] data, string filename, string contentType = null)
        {
            // Get the System.Web assembly reference
            Assembly systemWebAssembly = typeof(HttpPostedFileBase).Assembly;
            // Get the types of the two internal types we need
            Type typeHttpRawUploadedContent = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpRawUploadedContent");
            Type typeHttpInputStream = systemWebAssembly.GetType("System.Web.HttpInputStream");

            // Prepare the signatures of the constructors we want.
            Type[] uploadedParams = { typeof(int), typeof(int) };
            Type[] streamParams = { typeHttpRawUploadedContent, typeof(int), typeof(int) };
            Type[] parameters = { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeHttpInputStream };

            // Create an HttpRawUploadedContent instance
            object uploadedContent = typeHttpRawUploadedContent
                .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, uploadedParams, null)
                .Invoke(new object[] { data.Length, data.Length });

            // Call the AddBytes method
            typeHttpRawUploadedContent
                .GetMethod("AddBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Invoke(uploadedContent, new object[] { data, 0, data.Length });

            // This is necessary if you will be using the returned content (ie to Save)
            typeHttpRawUploadedContent
                .GetMethod("DoneAddingBytes", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Invoke(uploadedContent, null);

            // Create an HttpInputStream instance
            object stream = (Stream)typeHttpInputStream
                .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, streamParams, null)
                .Invoke(new object[] { uploadedContent, 0, data.Length });

            // Create an HttpPostedFile instance
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = (HttpPostedFile)typeof(HttpPostedFile)
                .GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, parameters, null)
                .Invoke(new object[] { filename, contentType, stream });

            return postedFile;
        }

        protected void UploadFile()
        {
            int successCount = 0;
            HttpFileCollection MyFileCollection = Request.Files;
            Response.Write("Total number file = " + dirs.Length + "<br/>");

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {

                byte[] fileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dir);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(dir);
                flagUpdateFile = 1;
                //Content Type is null
                Session["File"] = ConstructHttpPostedFile(fileData, fileName);

                //Token return from Google API
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]) && flagUpdateFile == 1)
                {
                    string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
                    string json = GoogleConnect.PostFile(code, (HttpPostedFile)Session["File"], "");
                    flagUpdateFile = 0;
                    System.IO.File.Delete(dir);
                    successCount++;
                }

                if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Access denied.')", true);
                    Console.Write("Access denied,check your Authorized redirect URIs!");
                }

                HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("File");
                HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();

            }
            Response.Write("Total file uploaded = " + successCount);
            successCount = 0;
            Response.Write("<span id='Label1' style='color:red'><br/>Sucess if the number is identical</span>");

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to MSDN you can setup it at web.config as:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but its says:

```
true: Arrays greater than 2 GB in total size are enabled on 64-bit platforms.
```

so its not work on 32bit, meaning that you also need to run your pool on 64-bit.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx

Comment: I had set this, but it is not work, here is the way i set http://postimg.org/image/7fk07kmsr/

Answer (score 2):

I admit I don't know the GoogleDrive API, but your code seems incredible complicated. Why do you do reflection at all and why for each file? Why do you load your whole file into a byte array just to put it in a `MemoryStream`, when you could be using a `FileStream` from the start, that doesn't copy your whole file into memory?

I'd say you need to simplify your code. All that Reflection? Write the actual two lines of code you *want* to write. Then use a filestream as [InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx).

You seem to want to fit all your files into a single request. The API seems to want you to fit a single file in one request. Maybe you should do that.

Comment: Hi, i foreach each file on a folder, because I want to upload multiple file in a folder. For MemoryStream that just a testing, i not deleted, that is not use in application. I foreach  a file because i want to get a name and data for a file.